# My slicer isn't filtering what's in my data cards just my table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need my slicer to give me the count of the specific name in the data cards. So when I select max only the count of Max shows but it isn't working and not changing from 212. enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question, add sample data and desired output i tabular form

Comment: When I select Max Goforth from the chiclet my cards aren't updating based on my selection in the chiclet. Why is that?